# MySQL Stored Procedure Returns Empty Result Set

Tags: mysql

The following stored procedure is returning an empty results set:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS indexCalc;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE indexCalc()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT MAX(coinIndex) FROM daily INTO n;
SET i=2;
WHILE i<n DO 
UPDATE daily AS d 
INNER JOIN(
SELECT
  A.coinId,
  B.coinIndex,
  A.index * (1+B.totalReturn) AS xxx
FROM
  daily A
LEFT JOIN
  daily B
    ON  B.coinIndex = A.coinIndex + 1
    AND B.coinID    = A.coinID) AS c 
 ON c.coinId = d.coinId
 AND c.coinIndex = d.coinIndex
 SET d.index = c.xxx
WHERE c.coinIndex = i;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;
```

The inner query executes properly when I substitute 2, 3, and so on for `i` in the `WHERE c.coinIndex = i` clause. The screenshot below shows the couple of rows that I executed manually.

[image]
Any idea why my procedure isn't looping through all records and executing the query as expected?

Thanks!

Comment: Your SP selects nothing into the output stream. Everything is correct, the resultset MUST be empty.

Comment: It's not clear why you need a loop in this procedure. I think you should be able to do it as a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Barmar Today's index is calculated based on yesterday's index. So that have to be updated sequentially. I may be incorrect but I think this requires a loop.

Comment: You can put `ORDER BY c.coinIndex` in the `UPDATE` query so it will process them sequentially.

Comment: @Barmar Struggling with where to place the ORDER BY. I've tried before and after the SET, as well as within the table C query.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) It goes after `SET` (after you remove the unneeded `WHERE`).

Comment: Error I'm getting is `incorrect usage of update and order by` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e83fe/1